# How to bend/create nice angle without warping model

Tags: modeling, 3d-printing

So I am doing some self learning by attempting to copy a phone stand that I have.

I am really close but I am not sure I understand how to create that triangle followed by a really nice bevel.

I have tried just doing a rotation but because it rotates by the center of what I select it just warps the model really badly.

Here is what I have so far:
[image: My model]

[Thingiverse model](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2418246)

Here is a picture of what I am attempting to copy. (I am not worrying about the bottom angle/bend)[image: Phone Stand]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have V angles, you should not have modeled rectangular angles in the first place, it's better to first follow the whole shape:

[image]

Extrude:

[image]

Give it a *Solidify* modifier (*Complex* mode to give it even thickness):

[image]

Apply the modifier, round the angles with bevel operations:

[image]

Correct the topology with the knife (<kbd>K</kbd> to activate, <kbd>Z</kbd> to cut through), dissolve unwanted edge loops with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>:

[image]

Give your object some *Boolean* modifiers in order to cut of the holes, etc:

[image]

Comment: Thank you I'll take a look at this later today. I haven't had an official blender course since my 3rd year of college so I am re-learning most of this. As of right now I really only know how to:
- CTRL+R to make a new line
  - From there I extrude up or out to where I need so I really only understand straight lines.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the solidify settings? I traced that same outline but when I apply the modifier I am not seeing it create the "inner" part. I have just been changing every setting possible but I am not seeing it do what you have.

Comment: You need first to extrude, I've edited my answer to be more clear. Also make sure that your modify is set to Mode > Complex

Comment: Thanks I think I got a really good setup for this. The biggest thing I am not sure I understand is "scale" because when I start from a cube and build everything myself I can control the size of everything. I guess I need to setup my reference image to be the correct size first.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, what's your problem with scale?

Comment: So I know that the bottom "base" area is 7mm wide and 8mm deep and .5mm tall. Just tracing it those aren't the dimensions I got on my finished model.

Comment: you can change the dimensions as much as you want, select the vertices and move them as you want so that it fits with your needs